# Blank page after a step to accept a license during Testlink installation

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp, testlink

I am seeing blank page on the http://localhost/testlink/install/installCheck.php?licenseOK=on step.

During the installation of the Testlink 1.9.20 on the XAMPP 8.2.4 on the macOS, after clicking Continue to accept the license agreement, I am presented with a blank page. I set paths as

```
$tlCfg->log_path = TL_ABS_PATH . 'logs' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

and

```
$g_repositoryPath = TL_ABS_PATH . 'upload_area' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

I have also altered permissions of the 3 folders to enable writing (logs, upload_area, gui/templates_c), but those steps were of no use.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Check the webserver error log to see what the cause may be.